# Bad edits accepted despite already being rejected

Tags: discussion

The review process does not seem to work like I thought it did.

I've seen plenty of bad edits where users have added superfluous information just to try and get reputation or changed the English so it is no longer valid or even reworded it so badly that the questions meaning has been changed entirely, in many of these cases I've seen conflicting accept/rejects but not really understood why.

Today a user edited my own question. He changed one sentence so it was no longer good English and incorrectly prefixed a method name with 'the'. To anyone reviewing it properly it would be obviously wrong.

I received a notification of a suggested edit so I *thought* that meant I'd get to review it myself, however it had been auto-accepted by 'Community'. Following that accept, somebody had correctly rejected it as a bad edit, but after that another user had accepted it, despite its being wrong and despite another user's having already rejected it.

Aren't edits only meant to get rejected or accepted once? How comes the second user can incorrectly override the decision? And are all edits initially accepted (by Community)? And is there a way for me to reject edits to my own questions or only the 'rollback' option?

Thanks for your time (Edit in question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5475063)

Comment: For the record, it really should be `it's`, the suggestion in that case really was correct. It is a contraction of `it is` in this context.

Comment: Yes I know, laziness when typing. I just didn't think it was worth editing again myself to add one apostrophe after I rolled back the edit!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You acceptance or rejection of a suggested edit to one of your own posts **is** binding, but that relies on you getting to the suggestion before enough other people have seen the suggestion and voted on it. On a smaller site you can pretty much guarantee that you'll get there in time. However, on Stack Overflow that's not always the case.

However in this particular case we see this:

> misterManSam reviewed this 2 hours ago: Edit
>   Michael Piefel reviewed this 2 hours ago: Edit

These two users clicked the "Improve" button and tweaked the edit before saving. One of them didn't clear the "this edit was useful" option so the suggester still got the +2 reputation.

The "Approve" action is attributed to Community. This is always the case.

Comment: Correct, Community is credited when the suggestion was improved but marked as not helpful (e.g. the *edit was useful* checkbox was unchecked).

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I've just checked and the suggester *did* get a +2 from this suggestion. So the checkbox can't have been cleared. Unless one user cleared it and the other didn't.

Comment: I thought Community is credited for an anonymous edit (accepted).

Comment: @ChrisF: race condition with two editors improving perhaps?

Comment: @AndriyM - this wasn't an anonymous suggestion - but one from a <2K rep user.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - That's what I'm thinking too.

Comment: @AndriyM: that too; but in case of an improved-but-rejected suggested edit, there has to be a revision to apply the 'rejected' edit in order for the 'improved' edit to show as a separate edit revision.

Comment: Actually I was thinking of an entirely different situation (Community as the author of an edit, not as a reviewer). Confused myself and you, sorry about that, @Martijn and Chris.

Comment: I don't see where Community is credited with the revision, actually. The [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25155727/revisions) now credits it to the original suggestor.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - could be down to race condition?

Comment: @ChrisF: ah, no, the *'Approve' review action* is credited to Community, which is always the case with an 'improve' action (as it requires a 'moderator' to push through the approve / reject action in that case).

Answer (score 0):

To accept/reject an edit, there are 3 votes necessary, not one (unless you are the OP, then your vote is binding). But if you edit the question/answer, there is a checkbox "suggested edit was helpful". This is a way to approve/reject with one vote (if you edit the post, at least).

Comment: As was this, I always thought it was a single vote. So it looks liek its 2 of 3 must agree?

Comment: @NickCardoso Yes, you cannot approve/reject an edit with a single vote, unless you are the OP or use the "Improve" button to edit.

Comment: @NickCardoso: the 'Improve' button can act as a veto; the action auto accepts or rejects the edit, depending on the state of the *edit is helpful* checkbox, in order to be able to apply the *improved* edit. This is regardless of what others voted.